# Show linear dependency of a ordered set of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

If $A$ is a $2\times 2$ matrix and the ordered set $= \{A^0,A^1,...A^4\}$. Then prove that the ordered set is linearly dependent.

I know that linear dependency means $a_0A^0+a_1A^1+...a_4A^4=0$ for $a_i\ne0$. But how can i prove this when A is not given in the question?

Comment: Do you know what the dimension of a vector space is? If not, you should recap that. I guess you already thought about the fact, that $2\times 2$-matrices are a vector space, if you talk about linearly dependence of matrices?

Answer (score 3):

You have $5$ matrices but the dimension is at most $4$.

Hence, they must be linearly dependent.

Answer (score 3):

In fact, $\{A^0, A^1, A^2\}$ are already linearly dependent. The characteristic polynomial of $A$ has degree $2$, so $p_A(X) = a_0 + a_1 X + a_2 X^2$. By Cayley-Hamilton, $0=p_A(A) = a_0 A^0 + a_1 A^1 + a_2 A^2$. Of course, using dimensions is much easier.

Comment: Cayley Hamilton is a bit a nuke here, but I like it.

Comment: @DionelJaime, Of course, but I was too much intrigued by the fact that already the first three vectors were linearly dependent.

Comment: I assume this is a warming up exercise for the Cayley-Hamilton theorem. At least that was the way our algebra course was structured. So using Cayley-Hamilton is certainly not a bad way, in fact, you helped the "foreshadowing". But it is important that the author see the trivial approach, too. Anyway, +1.

Comment: @A. Pongrácz Can you please tell what is the trivial approach?

Comment: @mathnewbie The trivial approach is the answer of Siong Thye Goh

Comment: @mathnewbie see my answer

Comment: @A. Pongrácz thanks

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Think about matrices as $4$-dimensional vectors.